# Why do so many Indians apparently despise the separation of powers?

Tags: india, public-opinion, separation-of-powers

A Pew [poll](https://www.pewresearch.org/short-reads/2024/02/28/who-likes-authoritarianism-and-how-do-they-want-to-change-their-government/sr_24-02-28_authoritarianism_1/):

[image]

The wording of the Q[s] was:

> "A system in which a strong leader can make decisions without interference from [country-specific legislative body, e.g. parliament or Congress] or the courts". Or "the military rules the country".

While I could ask the Q about other countries, Indians seem to top the charts (85%) in despising separation of powers and wanting one-man-rule (who might still be elected though.) **So why is disdain for separation of powers apparently so high in India?**

That poll partly answers the 'why' question by correlating answers to that Q with another one on disdain for opposition:

[image]

However, that can't be a full answer, because some 2/3 of Indians still want opposition to be able to "operate freely", thus what they want is not exactly a totalitarian system. So, are there additional reasons why the separation of powers is held in such low regard in India?

Comment: It's perhaps interesting to note that public opinion does not seem to relate one to one with whether a country has an authoritarian leader or military dictatorship, in any direction. In India, sure, Modi might be considered authoritarian and there seems to be strong support for that style of government. But then you have countries like Mexico or South Africa—high support, but not particularly authoritarian governments, and countries like Israel or Hungary—very low support, but more authoritarian leaders.

Comment: I do have a problem with the question, and suggest you delete or rephrase it.  You take a poll that asks a particular question.  We know that the exact phrasing of a poll question can have a big impact on the result.  You then change the phrasing to something that seems (to me) to make one particular ethnic group appear either foolish and naive, or anti-democratic, even totalitarian.  I've seen this type of question before and I don't think it should be on the system.

Comment: @JamesK: did you read the wording of the poll Q? "A system in which a strong leader can make decisions without interference from [country-specific legislative body, e.g. parliament or Congress] or the courts". Or "the military rules the country". I mean sure, one *can* argue that the word interference may be interpreted differently in different cultures. I'm not opposed to a "frame challenge" answer on those grounds, if it can be substantiated that Indians conceive of that kind 'interference' differently from other English speakers.

Comment: Separation of powers is an American virtue. The UK for instance has never had separation of powers (being a parliamentary not a presidential system), so maybe India is influenced by that. (And it's also a virtue if the courts aren't challenging the President, but ideally if the President obeys the law.)

Answer (score 6):

Authoritarianism (by its nature) is a reaction to the problems inherent in diversity. One of the known weaknesses of democratic forms of government is that they can grind to a standstill when opposed parties become unresponsive to debate and discussion. A nation like India — which has many religions, ethnic groups, and spoken languages — can generate a lot of opposition to any proposed action, with protracted legislative debates, extensive public opinion campaigns, court challenges, etc. It's slow, painful, aggravating, and makes many people **feel** like government isn't working (despite the fact that this is the process in action).

Authoritarian leaders bypass all of this by making and enforcing actions without legislative or judicial input. It's quick, efficient, and (if the leader is one of *your* guys) emotionally satisfying. A lot of people like the idea of it because they don't take the time to consider what will happen if that authoritarian efficiency is turned against them. They believe that a Hitler or a Putin or a Trump will make the trains run on time; they do not believe they will ever find themselves packed onto those trains headed for a labor camp because the leader decides *their* group is a problem.

It's worth noting that wannabe authoritarians are aware of this dynamic, and will actively sow discord, distrust, and intergroup hatred in order to break down democratic functioning, and then offer themselves as the cure. That's how authoritarians come to power in Liberal societies. If more people in India were aware of that, I doubt their support for authoritarianism would be so high.

Comment: Possibly, but only a minority of Indians (around 1/4) say that religious diversity hurts their country. About half say it doesn't https://www.pewresearch.org/religion/2021/06/29/diversity-and-pluralism/

Comment: I think this answer is on to something.  Even without the religious baiting aspects India seems to have a lot of dysfunction in how its government, courts and institutions are run.  A "strong leader who cuts the Gordian know of bullshit and corruption" may very well be something people hanker to.  "Drain the swamp!"

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat Keep in mind this could be a case of "I approve or am OK with this group of religions...but *this one* needs to be wiped off the face of the Earth".  Which could lead the belief holder to feel that, in general, they're okay with religious diversity and freedom, even though they are wholly intolerant of some particular group of religions, who they might blame for many problems. This is also the more palatable way of phrasing one's bigotry.  It is common for people with "unpopular", usually hateful, opinions to hide or mask them, even in an anonymous survey.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat Also your post's data is comparing support for the free activity of political parties with perception that an authoritarian leader would best resolve the country's problems.  Neither of those is directly an invocation of religion.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps people despise separation of powers because nobody is responsible for anything. You would hope that in a well-functioning republic with powers separation things would work smoothly, but when they aren't there's usually noone specific to blame.

A good comparison pair here would be the reaction of USSR's reaction to [Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster) vs. Indian reaction to [Bhopal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhopal_disaster). In the former case, the fact of disaster, the remediation attempts and public misinformation are all blamed on Communist Party and Gorbachev, who begrudgingly admit their responsibility because at the end of the day *there's nobody else there*. In the end it has affected the policy of USSR greatly, with some claims that it has contributed to the dissolution of USSR.

But in case of Bhopal: The disaster happened because of mismanagement of a commercial entity with legally limited responsibility, whose management has fled the country; Municipal government only did what they could with the resources they had; and the central Indian government, due to separation of powers, did not have to assign anybody between their own ranks as responsible. I would imagine that it would at best lead to local adjustment of policy, because there was nobody responsible for doing that on any larger scale.

Comment: Doesn't seem the most motivating example: "The Indian Government passed the Bhopal Gas Leak Act in March 1985, allowing the Government of India to act as the legal representative for victims of the disaster". And they then negotiated directly with UCC, although turned down the latter's initial offers. I suppose you could argue Indians also want capitalism abolished, and everything [big] state owned, which would indeed avoid such complications, but I doubt they really want that. Ok, maybe just everything Indian-owned like in Russia now, so the gov't can "crack oligarch heads" if needed.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat I'm not saying that military government *solves issues*, I just outline why people might *prefer* that. Preferences are not quite rational. Including preference for democracy :)

Comment: OTOH, you may be on to something "74% of Indians see capitalism doing 'more harm than good', reveals survey" https://www.cnbctv18.com/earnings/74-of-indians-see-capitalism-doing-more-harm-than-good-reveals-survey-5089061.htm India amost took the top in that poll, only Thailand has (negligibly) higher with 75% https://www.business-standard.com/article/international/global-majority-sees-capitalism-as-harmful-mistrust-high-in-india-survey-120012000335_1.html

Comment: That's funny because Thailand is highly capitalistically successful for an outsider. I wonder if there's a hidden societal cost that we're not seeing.

Comment: Yeah, "India #10 on ‘crony capitalism’ index" https://theprint.in/economy/india-10-on-crony-capitalism-index-how-the-economist-ranked-43-biggest-economies/1563224/